# Mac Pro won't sleep any more

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, mac-pro

The past couple days, command-option-eject no longer puts my Mac Pro to sleep.  I haven't done any software updates in that time.  No process seems to be doing anything very interesting, or CPU-intensive.

What's stopping my Mac from being able to sleep?  How can I figure out what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Terminal application in your utility and type

```
syslog |grep -i "Wake reason"
```

You shortcuts keys must have changed (with or without your intervention)

Make sure you have no hot corners enabled to keep it awake (System preferences Desktop > hot corners)

Comment: I get a few lines that look like: `kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EHC2`.  Google suggests that this is USB-related, and I remembered I've been using an old USB mouse recently because the batteries in my Bluetooth mouse died.  Unplugged the USB mouse, and my Mac sleeps again!

Answer (score 2):

Using the Terminal application on macOS Sierra 10.12 or later you can run the following:

`log show --last 2d|grep "Wake reason"`

This will provide a list of the various reasons your system is not sleeping. Unfortunately the list will likely contain a few things that are not immediately clear, but a quick search on those messages should lead you in the right direction.