# How do I figure out what is keeping my Mac Pro from sleeping?

Tags: macos, mac, sleep-wake

For some odd reason, my Mac Pro won't sleep by itself. Unlike, [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97867/mac-pro-wont-sleep-any-more), it does stay asleep; it just won't go to sleep by itself. I read [Why your Mac might not sleep or stay in sleep mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1776), but to no avail.

I tried `pmset -g assertions` and got this:

```
9/26/13 9:11:36 AM PDT   
Assertion status system-wide:
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   UserIsActive                   0
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   BackgroundTask                 0
```

And then a whole bunch of kernel assertions that had nothing set. What is going on?

Comment: I was on the wrong track and based on your negative vote I deleted my answer.

Comment: That's fine :) No problem. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you checked out the likely causes and solutions from this section (on an Apple KB) - "[How can I determine what is causing a sleep issue and how can I resolve it?](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1776)"?

Comment: Also see this answer on superuser for [What is preventing my MacBook from sleeping?](http://superuser.com/a/409481)

Comment: @MK Sorry, I forgot to add that. Yes I did.

Comment: I tried that answer. Nothing was listed. I did have iTunes playing and that did list it under `pmset -g`, but as soon as I paused it, there was nothing preventing sleep.